# How to check equality of annotations?

Tags: java, annotations, equals

How would you implement this method:

```
public boolean equal(Annotation a1, Annotation a2) {
   ...
}
```

Sample input ():

```
@First(name="1", value="1"), @Second(name="1", value="1")
@First(value="2"),           @First(name="2")
@First(value="3"),           @First(value="3")
@Second(name="4", value="4), @Second(name="4", value="4")
```

Sample output:

```
false
false
true
true
```

As you can see, the expected behavior of `equal` is clear and similar to expected behavior of standard `equals` method of regular objects in java (the problem is that we cannot override `equals` for annotations).

Are there any libs or standard implementations?

Comment: `a1.equals(a2);` will work.  This is the default behavior for annotations -  it checks that the annotations are of the same type and that each of the annotation fields are equal.  No special work arounds required.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't the [overriden equals](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) for `Annotation` work? Maybe I don't understand your question.

Comment: could you please show me how would you override `equals` on annotation class (let's take `@Sample` annotation as a start point; `equals` body doesn't really matter, just show where would you write it). thx.

Comment: It is already in Java for the annotations. Doesn't the default work for you? Have you looked at the link I provided? Maybe there is some misunderstanding...

Comment: maybe you're right, I'll investigate it (it's just not obvious how does it work since the actual `equals` implementation is somewhere else but not inside `Annotation` class).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether a1 and a2 are the same annotation. Try this:
a1.annotationType().equals(a2.annotationType())

Answer (score 0):

The annoying part of my answer is I can not extend a custom annotation (in the sense of inheritance). That would have simplified the equals method.

First.java

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface First  {
  String name() default "";
  String value() default "";
}
```

Second.java

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface Second {
    String name() default "";
    String value() default "";
}
```

Thing1.java

```
public class Thing1 {
     @First(name = "1", value ="1")
     Object leftSideCase1;
     @Second(name = "1", value ="1")
     Object rightSideCase1;

     @First(value ="2")
     Object leftSideCase2;
     @First(name = "2")
     Object rightSideCase2;

     @First(value ="3")
     Object leftSideCase3;
     @First(value ="3")
     Object rightSideCase3;

     @First(name = "4", value ="4")
     Object leftSideCase4;
     @First(name = "4", value ="4")
     Object rightSideCase4;
}
```

Example.java

```
public class Example {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException {
        String [][] fieldNameOfCases = {
                {"leftSideCase1","rightSideCase1"},
                {"leftSideCase2","rightSideCase2"},
                {"leftSideCase3","rightSideCase3"},
                {"leftSideCase4","rightSideCase4"},
        };

        // Loop through the list of field names, paired up by test case
        // Note: It's the construction of Thing1 that matches your question's
        // "sample input():"
        for(int index=0; index < fieldNameOfCases.length; index++) {
            Annotation leftSideAnnotation = getAnnotation(Thing1.class, fieldNameOfCases[index][0]);
            Annotation rightSideAnnotation = getAnnotation(Thing1.class, fieldNameOfCases[index][1]);
            System.out.println(equal(leftSideAnnotation, rightSideAnnotation));
        }
    }

    private static Annotation getAnnotation(Class<Thing1> thing1Class, String fieldName) throws NoSuchFieldException {
        Field classMemberField = Thing1.class.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        Annotation[] annotations = classMemberField.getAnnotations();
        // ASSUME ONE ANNOTATION PER FIELD
        return annotations[0];
    }

    // This is my solution to the question
    public static boolean equal(Annotation a1, Annotation a2) {
       if(a1.getClass() != a2.getClass()) {
           return false;
       }
       if(a1 instanceof First) {
           if( ((First)a1).name().equals(((First)a2).name())  &&
               ((First)a1).value().equals(((First)a2).value()) ) {
               return true;
           }
           return false;
       }
       // Its annoying we can't leverage inheritance with the custom annotation
       // to remove duplicate code!! 
       if(a1 instanceof Second) {
            if( ((Second)a1).name().equals(((Second)a2).name())  &&
                ((Second)a1).value().equals(((Second)a2).value()) ) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Note:** I did not introduce a NamePairValue holder to use within First, and Second (custom annotation) because this didn't match the "sample input():" **exactly**!

See this Stack Trace for details for this style / solution.
[How to extend Java annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126851/how-to-extend-java-annotation)

This question is 10 years old but the question was not answered as asked by Roman. With **4k views, I hope this helps someone**!!