# How to extend Java annotation?

Tags: java, annotations

In my project I use pre-defined annotation `@With`:

```
@With(Secure.class)
public class Test { //....
```

The source code of `@With`:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface With { 

    Class<?>[] value() default {};
}
```

I want to write custom annotation `@Secure`, which will have the same effect as `@With(Secure.class)`. How to do that?

---

What if I do like this? Will it work?

```
@With(Secure.class)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Secure {

}
```

Answer (score 40):

As piotrek pointed out, you cannot extend Annotations in the sense of inheritance. Still, you can create Annotations that aggregate others:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface SuperAnnotation {
    String value();
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface SubAnnotation {
    SuperAnnotation superAnnotation();
    String subValue();
}
```

Usage:

```
@SubAnnotation(subValue = "...", superAnnotation = @SuperAnnotation(value = "superValue"))
class someClass { ... }
```

Comment: So instead of writing `@With(Secure.class)`, OP now has to write `@Secure(superAnnotation = @With(Secure.class))`?  How does that help?

Answer (score 29):

From Java language specification, [Chapter 9.6 Annotation Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6):

> No extends clause is permitted. (Annotation types implicitly extend `annotation.Annotation`.)

So, you can not extend an Annotation. you need to use some other mechanism or create a code that recognize and process your own annotation. Spring allows you to group other Spring's annotation in your own custom annotations. but still, no extending.

Comment: Probably 'extend' is not best expression for this. I mean implementation of auto-placement for argument.

Comment: @bvitaliyg: you can create your own annotation with any default fields but there is no out-of-the-box mechanism in jvm that will recognize it automatically. you need to write that code by yourself or check if existing libraries (like spring) are sufficient for your case

Comment: For anyone looking to do this with Spring, it's worth knowing that the term Spring has for this is "meta-annotation". A "custom annotation" is just any annotation that you defined yourself, it doesn't necessarily mean that you meta-annotated it with a 3rd party annotation.

Answer (score 12):

To expand on Muhammad Abdurrahman's answer--

```
@With(Secure.class)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Secure {

}
```

This does **not** work by default but you **can** use it in conjunction with Spring's [AnnotationUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationUtils.html#findAnnotation-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Class-).

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18585833/6497736) for an example.

Answer (score 10):

```java
@With(Secure.class)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Secure {

}
```

This will work.

Comment: This is literally copied directly from the question.

Comment: @mkobit Well spotted. Since the questioner asked whether this would work in their question, my answer gets straight to the point and actually answers the question.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer to the question as asked... but only in the context of Spring, I believe (it only works if your annotation processors "walk" the annotation graph to the meta-annotation).

Comment: See the [answer by Eric Jiang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48028368/587365)

Comment: This does not work. I'm trying to create my own annotation for fields on classes annotated with JPA's `@Entity`. I wanted my annotation to do the same as `@Transient` plus other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can use annotation for annotation like this:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
@WithSecurityContext(factory = WithCustomUserSecurityContextFactory.class)
public @interface WithCustomUser {
  String username() default "demo@demo.com";
  String password() default "demo";
  String[] authorities() default {Authority.USER};
}
```

And define exact state in its "child"

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
@WithCustomUser(username = "admin@admin.com",
                password = "admin",
                authorities = {Authority.USER, Authority.ADMINISTRATOR})
public @interface WithAdminUser {
}
```

In this case you have a some kind of "state" and access to the parent annotation fields via reflection/aspect.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I was wondering if it is necessary to change the ElementType if I want a "child"-annotation. Apparently I don't have to change it if it applies to the same type as the parent one.

Answer (score 1):

So the provided answer from Eric Jiang is 100% working in my situation and she is:
I need JMSListener ,but i want to hide the destination name:

```
@GetPlayerDataByUUIDListener
    public void getPlayerDataByUUID(Object message) {
        System.out.println("Im Here");
    }
```

`

```
@JmsListener(destination = PlayerStatisticsJMSConstants.GET_PLAYER_DATA_BY_UUID)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface GetPlayerDataByUUIDListener {
}
```

So this is working perfectly ,and it is the same as:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "example")
    @GetPlayerDataByUUIDListener
    public void getPlayerDataByUUID(Object message) {
        System.out.println("Im Here");
    }
```