# Java - define name for annotation with parameters

Tags: java, annotations

I use an annotation with complex parameters frequently, e.g.:

```
@CookieValue(value = SomeClass.SOME_STATIC_FIELD, required = false) UUID cookieValue
```

Is it possible to define a new name for this annotation, so the above could be replaced like this?

```
@MyCookieValue UUID cookieValue
```

I tried the following, based on this: [How to extend Java annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126851/how-to-extend-java-annotation/22126884) Unfortunately, the syntax is not correct.

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyCookieValue {
    CookieValue cookieValue(value = SomeClass.SOME_STATIC_FIELD, required = false);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this:
`@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@CookieValue(value = SomeClass.SOME_STATIC_FIELD, required = false)
public @interface MyCookieValue {
}`
?

Comment: It shows the error message: `The annotation @CookieValue is disallowed for this location`. Spring `@CookieValue` is only applicable on parameters.